# Can YubiKey PIV and FIDO U2F be used together?

Tags: windows-10, smartcard

I setup my YubiKey for PIV authentication to my computer, and FIDO U2F for web app authentication. My issue is, whenever something requests FIDO access from my YubiKey, it disconnects the smart card. This creates a problem, because I want my computer to lock when the smart card is disconnected from the computer.

So, I guess my question is, can these services co-exist, or does my method of keeping my roommate out of my computer have a few flaws in it?